# Why did this answer get three First Answer review queue items?

Tags: bug, review, new-users

As can be seen in its [timeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20211015070352/https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/255005/timeline), a recent answer on Science Fiction & Fantasy ended up twice in the First Answers review queue: [[1]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/183607) and [[2]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/183608). This normally only happens in case of review audits; as the commenters here noticed, this time it seems an edit erroneously pushed it in the queue, which is clearly visible when looking at the timestamps (click 'toggle format' to show them):

[image]

(After this question was posted, the answer got a [third](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/183609) First Answers review item, unrelated to any visible action. The answer has since been deleted, so the timeline link has been replaced with a Wayback Machine snapshot.)

This is a different case than when two reviewers end up review the same item (because one of them took more than 5 minutes, which releases the 'soft lock' on the item so that it's open for other reviewers). Then we end up with one First Answer review item with two 'results'.

Comment: I think I've seen this before with edits, though I'm unsure of the exact criteria.

Comment: It seems like the last edit pushed it into the queue again.

Comment: Yes, it's the edit, thanks. I still think it's a bug :)

Comment: Maybe because it's an edit _by the OP_ and not so long after posting, so it needs to be re-reviewed? I can see how that could be part of the criteria. That said, apparently, it just had a _third_ First Answers review item and it's not linked with another event. Weird.

Comment: I think I saw this reported before, some review actions don't take the item out of the queue and are listed separately instead of being grouped. I couldn't find a reference to the previous post.

Comment: [Similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69625991/timeline) on SO. The edit was mine so that rules out the OP's edit hypothesis... (it was 25 minutes after the answer was posted, outside of any review queue)

Comment: Just for 'completeness', [here's one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69954693/timeline) where the review decision was "Looks OK" but, even then, a subsequent edit (by a different user) pushed it back into the queue. This would definitely appear to be a bug, unless the assumption is that an edit can make a First Answer no longer OK.

Comment: Since we're adding examples, here's [another](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/71687/timeline).